# Change index of VC in page view controller (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

Using the following code, I have a series of view controllers embedded in a page view controller that I'm swiping through. I just can't find a way to segue to another view controller via a bar button press. I'm planning on writing a separate function for each bar button icon in each view controller.

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    private var pages: [UIViewController]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self

        self.pages = [
            self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstNav") as! UINavigationController,
            self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondNav") as! UINavigationController,
            self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdNav") as! UINavigationController,
            self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FourthNav") as! UINavigationController
        ]

        let startingViewController = self.pages.first! as UIViewController
        self.setViewControllers([startingViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let index = (self.pages as NSArray).indexOfObject(viewController)

        // if currently displaying last view controller, return nil to indicate that there is no next view controller
        return (index == self.pages.count - 1 ? nil : self.pages[index + 1])
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let index = (self.pages as NSArray).indexOfObject(viewController)

        // if currently displaying first view controller, return nil to indicate that there is no previous view controller
        return (index == 0 ? nil : self.pages[index - 1])
    }

}
```

Comment: You are trying to segue from which view controller to which view controller, and where did you try putting the bar button?

Comment: The above code is code for the page view controller. The bar button code goes in all of the child view controllers since they have different buttons. I need to segue from FirstNav to ThirdNav and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your implementation of `PageViewController` to the following (I made some changes in the methods you already implemented, and I added a new instance method.)

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    private var pages: [UINavigationController]!

    private var currentPageIndex: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self

        self.pages = [
            self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstNav") as! UINavigationController,
            self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondNav") as! UINavigationController,
            self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdNav") as! UINavigationController,
            self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FourthNav") as! UINavigationController
        ]

        (self.pages[0].topViewController as! FirstViewController).parentPageViewController = self
        (self.pages[1].topViewController as! SecondViewController).parentPageViewController = self
        (self.pages[2].topViewController as! ThirdViewController).parentPageViewController = self
        (self.pages[3].topViewController as! FourthViewController).parentPageViewController = self

        self.currentPageIndex = 0
        let startingViewController = self.pages.first! as UINavigationController
        self.setViewControllers([startingViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let index = (self.pages as NSArray).indexOfObject(viewController)
        self.currentPageIndex = index

        // if currently displaying last view controller, return nil to indicate that there is no next view controller
        return (self.currentPageIndex == self.pages.count - 1 ? nil : self.pages[self.currentPageIndex + 1])
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let index = (self.pages as NSArray).indexOfObject(viewController)
        self.currentPageIndex = index

        // if currently displaying first view controller, return nil to indicate that there is no previous view controller
        return (index == 0 ? nil : self.pages[index - 1])
    }



    func displayPageForIndex(index: Int, animated: Bool = true) {
        assert(index >= 0 && index < self.pages.count, "Error: Attempting to display a page for an out of bounds index")

        // nop if index == self.currentPageIndex
        if self.currentPageIndex == index { return }

        if index < self.currentPageIndex {
            self.setViewControllers([self.pages[index]], direction: .Reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if index > self.currentPageIndex {
            self.setViewControllers([self.pages[index]], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        self.currentPageIndex = index
    }

}
```

Now, in each of your child view controllers, add two pieces of code:

1. A property that maintains a weak reference to the parent `PageViewController` instance.

   ```
   weak var parentPageViewController: PageViewController!
   ```
2. An `IBAction` to which you connect each of your bar button items. You may need to change the body of this method depending on how your Storyboard is set up.

   ```
   @IBAction func barButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

       var newIndex = -1

       switch sender.title! {
       case "First":
           newIndex = 0
       case "Second":
           newIndex = 1
       case "Third":
           newIndex = 2
       case "Fourth":
           newIndex = 3
       default: break
       }

       self.parentPageViewController.displayPageForIndex(newIndex)
   }
   ```

Comment: Since I knew which button would correspond to which page, I scrapped the entire `switch` statement. The `.displayPageForIndex()` method did the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: Suppose I have an array of navigation controllers like I currently do, but also a separate view controller outside of the page view controller. Since I can't segue directly from the page view controller, is it possible to instantiate this separate VC within the page view controller, and switch to the incumbent array of navigation controllers from that other vc? @ndmeiri

Answer (score 0):

Does each controller need to be embedded in a `UINavigationController`?  You could just have a `UINavigationController` embed a single `UIViewController`, that view controller references a `pageviewcontroller` and a `barButtonItem`, when the `barButtonItem` is tapped trigger an action that tells the `pageviewcontroller` to change indexes.

Or if you want to go with your current plan of action which is a `barButtonItem` in each `UINavigationController`, write a protocol with a delegate method `didSelectBarButtonAtIndex` or something, then give each `UINavigationController` a delegate property, have the `pageviewcontroller` conform to the protocol and become the delegate for each nav controller.  Then when a bar button is tapped, call the delegate method, which should make the page controller change it's index.

Comment: Yeah, each view controller has its own nav controller. And I'm adding each bar button to a custom view in each view controller, not nav controller.